# Inserting recyclerView by amount of number got from TCP Server?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, cardview

I'm trying to make a simple `recyclerView` with a `cardView` in a `scrollView`
that will create a new view by setting it by number, actually my app will receive a string from the **TCP Server** with a number, and i have to create the same amount of `recyclerView` as the number sent by **TCP Server**, i've made already a `cardView`, here is the code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="180dp"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="163dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/self_picture"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/selfcassa" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/n_cassa"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/self_picture"
            android:text="CASSA SELF N°1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/red"
            android:textSize="42sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Here is the **RecyclerViewSelf** (`recyclerViewAdapter`) :

```
public class RecyclerViewSelf extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewSelf.ViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<String> selfList;

public RecyclerViewSelf(ArrayList<String> selfList){
    this.selfList = selfList;
}


@Override
public RecyclerViewSelf.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View contactView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.self_blueprint, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(contactView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewSelf.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    viewHolder.n_cassa.setText(selfList.get(position));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return selfList != null ? selfList.size() : 0;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private TextView n_cassa;
    private ImageView img;
    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        n_cassa = view.findViewById(R.id.n_cassa);
        img = view.findViewById(R.id.self_picture);
        }
    }

}
```

And here is the activity where i **recall the RecyclerView**:

```
public class help extends AppCompatActivity {

private ArrayList selfList;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_help);
    Utils.darkenStatusBar(this, R.color.colorAccent);
    ImageButton home = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.casa);

    initViews();

    home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
         finish();
        }
    });
}

private void initViews(){
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewSelfMachine);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    selfList = new ArrayList<>();
    selfList.add("CASSA SELF N°1");
    selfList.add("CASSA SELF N°2");
    selfList.add("CASSA SELF N°3");
    selfList.add("CASSA SELF N°4");
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = new RecyclerViewSelf(selfList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

UPDATED QUESTION

Actually i've created a `recyclerView` where i set the data and it visualize 4 `cardViews`, but now i would create number of `cardView` got from the **TCP Server** or i get a `string` with a number from the **TCP Server** to the **TCP Client**, and now i would create the number of `cardViews` that i've got in the string sent by **TCP Server**.

Comment: `recyclerView.setAdapter(self);` self i.e. the code shown (here the Adapter) doesn't look like an adapter class at all. I'd try removing this line. You might also need to have `recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());`

Comment: actually by adding the Animator and removing setAdapter nothing changed that still visualize just the scroll view without the cardView

Comment: Opps my bad, concentrating on why two setAdapters and missed setting self to be adapter. Only 1 of the adpaters is needed though. However, the **selflist** ArrayList is only declared (`selfList = new ArrayList<>();`) so will have no data to be listed,

Comment: Updated question, now i can create the (recyclerView) but for now the one who set it amount it's me, check the updated question please.

Comment: where you are performing TCP operation in your code? @I.Mytyuk

Comment: in MainActivity, the TCP Server string is yet static so i can get it in the activity where i evokate the recyclerView without any problem

Comment: you can invoke TCP call after setAdapter Method @I.Mytyuk

Comment: actually i don't need to invoke TCP again but just on start of the application. i just have to set amount of cardViews = amount set in String i've received from TCP Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I fully understand what you're asking but the following appears to do what I interpret you as asking for.

```
    private void initViews(int tcpcount){
        String base = "CASSA SELF N°";
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewSelfMachine);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        selfList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0; i < tcpcount; i++) {
            selfList.add(base + Integer.toString(i+1));
        }
        RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = new RecyclerViewSelf(selfList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Obviously you'd change the call of initView from `initViews();` to `initViews(tcpnumber_as_int);`

Answer (score 1):

remove as you initialise another Adapter as shown below

```
RecyclerViewSelf selfrecycler = new RecyclerViewSelf(this, selfList);
```

use

```
 recyclerView.setAdapter(self);
```

**insted of**

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(selfrecycler);
```

method should be like this

```
private void prepareSelf() {
             Self s = new Self("CASSA SELF 1");
             selfList.add(s);
             self.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Now i fixed it by rebuilding the RecyclerView, i updated the code but now i have another issue check the updated question.